# ESXi5 - management services crashes - vms running

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have a setup with two ESXi5 servers.

We are(were) running with a ISCSi box to server disk for the VM's - however we are in the progress of migrating away from it, because the storage os disk is bad.

Now, one of the ESXi hosts has been running for ~20hrs, and it seems like the management services just crashed on that host..

The vms are still running - so it's not really serious. However, I want to fix it.

Should I be worried? Will the VM's keep running?

The hosts does respond on pings.

I am running a vcenter to administrate the hosts.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I have now managed to get the services running:

```
~ # /etc/init.d/vpxa status
vpxa is running
~ # /etc/init.d/hostd status
hostd is running.
```

But the server is still not responding on either VMware vSphere Client nor the webinterface.

I can however use paping on both port 80 and 443 to the server, which works brilliant.

I would like some help to move on in this case.

Comment: Are your servers HCL compliant?

Comment: I would definately think so - It is Fujitsu RX300S5's.
The system has been running fine for the last few years, so it is a recent issue that came up right around when the storage started to mess with us.

Comment: Im experiencing the same problem. All of my Virtual machines are running fine except my two vcenter appliances. Since my vCenter appliances and the management interface are down i cant get into the esxi host to migrate the VM's to another host. I tried restarting the managment interface but had no luck. The issue was the result of our SAN dropping a node for about 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log on to the console of the server in question and restart the management agents

- Press F2 to customize the system.
- Log in.
- Select "Restart Management Agents"

VMWare also details this process for ESXi 5 in [this knowledgebase article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003490).

Comment: Thats just a temporary solution I think - any idea on how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: No, it's not a temporary solution. Sometimes this happens... even in stable installations. That's why VMWare made it an option in the management interface.

Comment: Okay, will try it out when I hit the office tomorrow.

Comment: I'd consider it a step in diagnosis...if it continues to crash shortly after restarting, you may have a problem. If it seems stable after restarting, it could have been a fluke.

Comment: Could it have something to do with an underpowered vCenter server?

Comment: I don't *think* so. I just know that restarting the management agents is a normal troubleshooting step.

Comment: Allright, I pressed restart management agents - and now they are just hanging on "Starting management agents." - any clue?

Comment: You may need to do it the hard way if it fails from the service console. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005566

Comment: @AaronCopley - tried to do exactly as on the URL you sent, without success.. Seems like its gonna be a hard reboot tomorrow.

Comment: Suddently the management services started responding this morning - and then crashed again.. A reboot seems to have fixed the problem.